# Outputing the contents of an array list

Tags: java

How would it be possible to return the values in the arraylist onto the screen e.g. System.out.println

I was thinking of a for loop e.g.

```
for (String s : list)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

But it complains it can't convert an object to string - how can I convert it to string?

**Code:**

```
public static void GetStatsProc(String operation)
{
     try { 
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(operation); 
        p.waitFor(); 
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
        String line=reader.readLine(); 
        while(line!=null) 
        { 
            // Add all lines into an array
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.add(line);
            System.out.println(line); 
            line=reader.readLine(); 
        } 

     }
     catch(IOException e1) {}
     catch(InterruptedException e2) {}   
}
```

Comment: You should be using a generic `ArrayList` (i.e. `ArrayList<String>`).

Comment: Nobody else has pointed out that you are declaring a new list at each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Why doesn't your example code contain the foreach loop?  Where do you want to put it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your issue is with printing in the for loop, then your list should be declared

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and the for loop needs to look like

```
for (String s : list)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the code:

```
 System.out.println(list);
```

To print your list.

Comment: That only works because ArrayList has an overridden toString() (actually way down in AbstractCollection), so it's not often going to be the thing you want, except for debugging.

Comment: Agreed, however if it is a simple `List<String>` like OP's code then it will print it fine.

Comment: My comment was more for posterity, and not really aimed at you, since this question is a newbie Java programmer learning about collections and generics.  Some other newbie may read this, and I just wanted the caveats available to them.

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing a : in your code, it should be for (String s : list) then you can reference s as long as you have a list of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every object has a `toString()` method, although the default implementation might not provide good results. In your case, however, you're dealing with lists of strings and thus you should use `ArrayList<String>`, as the others already suggested.

In case you want to loop over the entries and provide your own formatting (like line breaks etc.), try this:

```
for (Object o : list)
{
  System.out.println(o);
}
```

This will internally call `String.valueOf(o)` which will call `o.toString()` or return `"null"` if `o` is `null`.